# How to present modal view in "parentViewController"?

Tags: ios, showmodaldialog

I'm trying to write iPad app.

I have `UIViewController` as **parentViewController** (full screen) for **masterView** and **detailView** (my handmade splitView). Also I have a separate view (for example **moreDetailView**) with class and xib, which I would like to show as modal.

**masterView** has `UITableView` and **detailView** has `UICollectionView`. Both of them has own classes and xib. In **detailView** there are several items.

In my **didSelectItemAtIndexPath:** of **detailView** I would like to show **moreDetailView**.

So, how can I do that? And how to show it in **parentViewController**, but **NOT** in **detailView**.

Hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will present your controller in a modal formsheet (you can change this with the setModalPresentationStyle) on the top of your splitView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIViewController *moreDetailViewController = [[MoreDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [moreDetailViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; //or style depending on what you want
    [moreDetailViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    [self presentViewController:moreDetailViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        //stuff you want to do after the viewController has been presented
    }]; }
```

Comment: is there any method to make dark gradient of back view like in UIAlertView?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `masterview` and `detailview` in `parentview`. To access the `parentcontroller` you can declare a property in `detailcontroller` as

```
UIViewController *parent;
```

and while initializing you can do

```
detailController.parent=self;
```

and while showing modal you can do

```
[parent presentModal]; //instead of [self presentModal];
```

I hope above works for you, you will need to correct the syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIViewController *moreDetailViewController = [[MoreDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [moreDetailViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; //or style depending on what you want
    [moreDetailViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    [self presentViewController:moreDetailViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        //stuff you want to do after the viewController has been presented
    }];
}
```